# How can I program a button on an Access form to link to a browser window that looks up multiple addresses on Google Maps?

Tags: forms, api, google-maps, ms-access, vba

My problem is very similar to the one posted here:

```
http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Plotting-Addresses-Maps-t1968130.html
```

except that thread never found any solutions. Basically, I'm working on an Access form that has a datasheet as a subform. Upon clicking a button on the main form I'm trying to make it so that a browser window opens up and, using the address columns from the spreadsheet data in the subform, plot all the address markers listed. I've looked up a lot of ways to attempt this but I've yet to find a way that seems to work.

I'm not even sure if it's possible to plot multiple markers on Google Maps, but according to research (and after trying it myself) it seems like it isn't, although I don't want to rule it out entirely because I'm still not 100% sure. However I know both Google Earth and batchgeo.com do allow this. I still want to try and do this on Google Maps, but if that doesn't work I want to try to do it using batchgeo.com and if that still doesn't work, then Google Earth (I don't want to make the user download external software if possible).

If it helps, from what I've read API's seem like a useful tool, though I'm not sure how to apply it to an Access form, it seems more like a way to embed to already existing websites.

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me figure out how to approach this problem!

Comment: It's certainly possible to plot multiple markers on a google map in a browser, using the Google Maps API.

Comment: Thanks, that's really good to know, now I know that part is possible!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919374/implement-google-maps-on-a-access-form

Comment: You have multiple problems in your question. you should break them into shorter quesitons and ask those separetely.

Comment: I second kurast's comment. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557432/is-it-possible-to-display-a-google-earth-map-inside-excel

Comment: Okay, I'll try that kurast, thanks. And thanks Remou, I saw that video yesterday and had problems with it so I didn't use it, but I think I'll try asking that as a seperate question. Jean-Francois Corbett, I wasn't really looking to do the map through Excel, but thanks anyway


EDIT: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do here, I made another thread simplifying a part of my question and Remou down voted my post and marked it as a duplicate (although it wasn't) so I don't think anyone else is going to respond. Is there a better way to get help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help?

http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/getmaps/mapmarkers

It is Excel but should be translatable.

Here is another example, this time using Access:
http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Google-Maps-Multiple-Mar-t1973499.html

Answer (score 0):

> ...from what I've read API's seem like a useful tool, though I'm not
>   sure how to apply it to an Access form, it seems more like a way to
>   embed to already existing websites.

You're right. There's no way, that I'm aware of, to embed a Google Maps object in a form (like an ActiveX control). [Microsoft MapPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674717.aspx) is a software product that lets you do Map integration by way of an ActiveX control (no need to use HTML and/or javascript).

What I usually do on a project like you're working on is I get my HTML page working the way I want it to, outside and independent of MS Access. You should be able to program and test the HTML file locally without having to use an actual web server. Just use something like NotePad++ or Sublime Text Editor 2 to write your HTML and Javascript and then open the file in your browser to see if it works. I'm quite sure you'll need to use Javascript in your HTML page to make this work. That's what the Google Maps API is all about.

After you have your webpage working, then you will have to go into Access and write code to create that web page on the fly with the address data for the current data set. You can just write it out to the Windows Temp folder and then open your browser control that that web page.

Julian Knight's answer links to more specifics on how to create the HTML page on the fly. It looks like gobble-de-gook, mostly because it is. Outputting HTML/Javascript/CSS from VBA is far less than optimal. This is why you troubleshoot it outside of Access, as much as you can.